# previous HTML won't render with back button after history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I have the below HTML which is served from `GET /home` and uses Javascript to hijack the form submit event in order to change the method from POST to DELETE. The server listening for requests to `DELETE /delete` which actually return a 303 redirect to `GET /new` which serves some HTML. The Javascript updates the address bar to `example.com/new` using the history API, and renders the HTML using using `window.document.documentElement.innerHTML = text`. This all works find, and when I click the back button the address bar DOES change back to the previous address (example.com/home) but the HTML is not rendered. Why is this? I've read the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) but I can't find anything about not rendering HTML, surely if the back button updates the address bar, the page should be updated to that URL? I also tried using `history.replaceState()` but it didn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/delete" method="POST">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      <input name="key" value="val" />
    </form>
  </body>
  <script>
    const form = document.querySelector("form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", async e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(new URLSearchParams(new FormData(e.currentTarget)));
      const response = await fetch(form.action, {
        body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(e.currentTarget)),
        method: "DELETE",
        redirect: "follow",
      });
      const text = await response.text();
      history.pushState({}, "", response.url);
      // history.replaceState({}, "", response.url);
      window.document.documentElement.innerHTML = text;
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you are replacing innerHTML, which includes the script part as well. Please move your script to head tag (if it is possible) or instead replacing innerHTML of the whole document, make a parent div and replace the content of that div.

So instead of this -

```
window.document.documentElement.innerHTML = text;
```

Do this -

```
documemt.getElementById('SomeDIV').innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Putting the script in <head> doesn't appear to work because the DOM will not have loaded so when the script runs it will not find the form element. I can't wrap the content in a div, the best solution seemed to be replace document.body instead, but this also seems to destroy the script.

Comment: I have tried using `window.onload = () => { myscript }` and putting the script in head. The script now sucessfully runs and finds the form, however the original question is not solved - the previous page is not rendered when navigated to with the back button.